# changing my code according to checkbox in JS

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, fetch, innerhtml

My code is fetching a server data, that calculates a number from a fibonacci server accordingly to the value the user enters.

I have added a spinner loader, that is responsive to the click
and the number 42 is blocked by the server and sends back an error, which i needed to figure out the name of the error, and present it to the user.

If the number was bigger than 50, I needed to present an error to the user as well.

Lastly, I created a list of the numbers prev submitted to the server in the innerHTML.

```
const clcBtn = document.getElementById("calcButton");
let clcInput = document.getElementById("calcInput");
const result = document.getElementById('paragraph');
const loader = document.getElementById('spinner');
const error = document.getElementById('error-message');
const serverError = document.getElementById('server-error');
const numbersOne = document.getElementById('numbersOne');
const numbersTwo = document.getElementById('numbersTwo');
const numbersThree = document.getElementById('numbersThree');
const numbersFour = document.getElementById('numbersFour');
const checkbox = document.getElementById('saveCheck');
const areusure = document.getElementById('changeMind');



clcBtn.addEventListener("click", calcFunc);

function numValidate(value) {
  if(value > 50) {
    return false; 
  } 
  
  return true;
}


function calcFunc() {
  if (!numValidate (clcInput.value)) {
    error.style.display = "block"
    setTimeout(() => {
      error.style.display = "none";
    }, 5000);
    console.error("Can't be larger than 50") // only bec it's a cool feature :D
    
    return;
  }

   if (clcInput.value == 42){
    serverError.style.display = "block";
    
    return;
   }



   
   
   
   
   loader.classList.add("spinner-border");
   
   fetch(`http://localhost:5050/fibonacci/${clcInput.value}`).then(function (response) {
     return response.json().then(function (data) {
       result.innerHTML = data.result;
      // printNumbers();
    });
  });
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    loader.classList.remove("spinner-border");
  }, 600);
}

function printNumbers() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:5050/getFibonacciResults`).then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (data) {
      numbersTwo.innerHTML = data.results.map(item => {
        
        
        
        
        
        
        return `<span class='itemOne'>
        <span>The fibonacci of ${item.number} is ${item.result}. Calculated at: ${item.createdDate = Date(3)}</span>
        </span>`;
      }).join('');
      
      
      numbersThree.innerHTML = data.results.map(item => {
        return `<span class='itemTwo'>
        <span>The fibonacci of ${item.number} is ${item.result}. Calculated at: ${item.createdDate}</span>
        </span>`;
      }).join('');
      
      
      
      
      numbersFour.innerHTML = data.results.map(item => {
        return `<span class='itemThree'>
        <span>The fibonacci of ${item.number} is ${item.result}. Calculated at: ${item.createdDate}</span>
        </span>`;
      }).join('');
      
      
      numbersOne.innerHTML = data.results.map(item =>  {
        return `<span class='itemFour'>
        <span>The fibonacci of ${item.number} is ${item.result}. Calculated at: ${item.createdDate}</span>
        </span>`;
      }).join('');
          
    });
  });
};
```

What I need to do now, is to add a checkbox, that checks if the user wants to save the calculations in the innerHTML.

If the user checks the box, the calculations will be calculated by the server and presented and saved on the page through the innerHTMl..

What I have tried to do:

```
checkbox.addEventListener("change", event=>{
    if (!checkbox){
        numbers.innerHTML += `${data.number}  ${data.result}  ${data.createdDate} <br/>`;
      }
      else if (checkbox) {
      return false;}
```

I have tried to write it in here:

```
function printNumbers() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:5050/getFibonacciResults`).then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (data) {
      numbersTwo.innerHTML = data.results.map(item => {
```

right after the last curly bracket.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: because it is part of the code below.. brackets do not close yet.
Read the code please.

Comment: anyone? please?

Comment: Ok, I try again. Your FETCH is invalid. You need to close the brackets before the next .then

Answer (score 0):

Your FETCH is invalid. You need to close the brackets before the next .then

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5050/getFibonacciResults')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(data) {
    numbersTwo.innerHTML = data.results
      .map(item => { return `<span>${item.number...}</span>` })
      .join("");
  });
```

or

```
fetch('http://localhost:5050/getFibonacciResults')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => numbersTwo.innerHTML = data.results
      .map(item => `<span class='itemOne'>The fibonacci of ${item.number} is ${item.result}. Calculated at: ${item.createdDate = Date(3)}</span>`)
      .join("");
  });
```

I do not understand why you have 4 elements getting the same result

If you want to store them elsewhere then add to the fetch:

```
const result = data.results
      .map(item => `<span class='itemOne'>The fibonacci of ${item.number} is ${item.result}. Calculated at: ${item.createdDate = Date(3)}</span>`)
      .join("");
numbersTwo.innerHTML = result;
if (checkbox.checked) numbers.innerHTML += `${result}<hr/>`;
```

If you want to store the results already on the page, give the elements the same class and do

```
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.innerHTML = this.checked ? [...document.querySelectorAll(".number")].map(span => span.innerHTML).join("<hr/>") : "";
});
```

Your code with my GUESSES

```js
const clcBtn = document.getElementById("calcButton");
const clcInput = document.getElementById("calcInput");
const result = document.getElementById('paragraph');
const loader = document.getElementById('spinner');
const error = document.getElementById('error-message');
const serverError = document.getElementById('server-error');
const numbersOne = document.getElementById('numbersOne');
const checkbox = document.getElementById('saveCheck');
const areusure = document.getElementById('changeMind');

const numValidate = value => value > 0 && value <=50;

const printNumbers = (data) => { 
  const result = data.results.map(item => `<span class='itemOne'>
    The fibonacci of ${item.number} is ${item.result}. 
    Calculated at: ${item.createdDate = Date(3)}</span>`).join('');
  numbersOne.innerHTML = result;
  if (checkbox.checked) result.innerHTML += `${result}<hr/>`;
};

const calcFunc = ()  => {
  const value = +clcInput.value; // convert to number
  if (!numValidate(value)) {
    error.style.display = "block"
    setTimeout(() => {
      error.style.display = "none";
    }, 5000);
    console.error("Can't be larger than 50") // only bec it's a cool feature :D
    return; // stop
  }
  if (value == 42) {
    serverError.style.display = "block";
    return;
  }
  else serverError.style.display = "none";

  loader.classList.add("spinner-border");

  fetch(`http://localhost:5050/fibonacci/${clcInput.value}`) // this should RETURN the data!
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      loader.classList.remove("spinner-border");
      printNumbers(data);
    });

};
clcBtn.addEventListener("click", calcFunc);
```

Comment: and about my question?

Comment: is it just me? or taking parts of a code and re applying it never works?
i did exactly what u told me.. step by fkin step.. and nothing works.
can u provide me the whole code to review it with my vscode? 
i understand a little bit of what u said.. but still don't get the bigger picture.
i need tu actually understand every piece of what u said in order to build a carreer.
thanks for the help so far.. it was huge u have no idea.

Comment: I cannot help better -    you only posted partial code. I do not know what parts of the code works for you and I still do not have any idea why you have 4 elements you show the same data in. Please add relevant HTML and draw a picture of what you expect the result should look like

Comment: See my GUESSED example.

Comment: i have seen it.. and it does not help me..
i need to figure out hirarcy of the code..
what executes first, and then i need to figure out where i can put whatever i want, and how to actually write this.
i am taking a real hard core course, and it's painfully hard to keep up with it.

Comment: Then I have no clue how to help you.